# sharepoin Online - Lync presence is distorted

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint-online

I have migrated sites from SP 2010 to SP Online, and the lync presence is distorted as below, no idea why is this happening

is there any other way in SP Online to get the lync presence?
[image: This is the view where little square gets distorted]

Comment: Does any one has any idea on this please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Below code worked for me and is now displaying as expected

```
<span class="ms-verticalAlignTop ms-noWrap ms-displayInlineBlock"> 
<span class="ms-imnSpan"><a href="#" onclick="IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;" class="ms-imnlink ms-spimn-presenceLink"> 
    <span class="ms-spimn-presenceWrapper ms-imnImg ms-spimn-imgSize-10x10"><img name="imnmark" title="" showofflinepawn="1" class="ms-spimn-img ms-spimn-presence-online-10x10x32" 
        src="/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png" alt="Available" sip="david.schwarz@bayer.com" id="imn_715,type=sip"> 
    </span> 
</a> 
</span> 
<span class="ms-noWrap ms-imnSpan"><a href="#" onclick="IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;" class="ms-imnlink" tabindex="-1"> 
 <img name="imnmark" title="" showofflinepawn="1" class=" ms-hide" src="/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png" alt="Available" 
    sip="david.schwarz@bayer.com" id="imn_716,type=sip"></a> 
       <a class="ms-subtleLink" onclick="GoToLinkOrDialogNewWindow(this);return false;" href="http://connections.bayer.com/profiles/html/profileView.do?email= david.schwarz@bayer.com ">David Schwarz</a> 
</span>
```

[This is the reference article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18728.sharepoint-2013-how-to-show-user-presence-on-mouse-hover.aspx)